Python not buffering audio correctly
I have a python script that fetches audio file from GCS and is meant to buffer only a max of 10 seconds of audio each time per chunk.
However it is not working, it starts off good but when a long file say 2 hours long, it ends up being out by a lot. Say the current play head is 4min it has buffered 5min total that's 60 seconds out.
It's meant to act like a live stream.
def generate_audio(audio_file, bitrate_str, sample_rate_str, audio_size_str):
    print(audio_file)
    
    # Convert bitrate, sample rate, and audio size to integers
    bitrate = int(bitrate_str)
    print('bitrate is')
    print(bitrate)

    sample_rate = int(sample_rate_str)
    audio_size = int(audio_size_str)
    print(audio_size)

    # Set up the start position for reading chunks from the file
    start_position = 0
    part1_runs = 0

    # Set the initial desired duration
    initial_desired_duration = 0.00000499  # seconds per chunk
    remaining_duration = calculate_remaining_duration(audio_size, start_position, bitrate, sample_rate)
    desired_duration = min(initial_desired_duration, remaining_duration)
    delay = 0.01
    count = 0
    # Stream the audio data chunks to the client
    while True:
        # Calculate the chunk size based on the current desired duration
        chunk_size = calculate_chunk_size(bitrate, sample_rate, initial_desired_duration)
        print (chunk_size)
        # Example values

        duration = calculate_audio_duration(chunk_size, sample_rate, 44100)
        print("Duration of audio in chunk:", duration, "seconds")

        # Ensure that the end position for the chunk does not exceed the file size
        end_position = min(start_position + chunk_size, audio_size)

        # Read a chunk of data from the audio file
        chunk = audio_file.download_as_string(start=start_position, end=end_position)

        # If no more data is available, break the loop
        if not chunk:
            break

        # Update the start position for the next chunk
        start_position += len(chunk)

        # Update the remaining duration
        remaining_duration = calculate_remaining_duration(audio_size, start_position, bitrate, sample_rate)
        # Round to the nearest second
        print("Remaining duration (rounded to nearest second):", remaining_duration, "seconds")
      
        
        if count >= 0.68:
           
            sleepDur = remaining_duration/1000

          
            sleepDur = str(sleepDur).split(".")[0]
            # Convert the value to a string and slice it to include only the first five digits after the decimal point
            if part1_runs >= 10:
                time.sleep(0.68)
                part1_runs = 3
            elif part1_runs > 8:
                print("sleeping for 3 seconds")
                time.sleep(3)
            elif part1_runs < 8:
                print(float(sleepDur) + part1_runs)
                time.sleep(1)
        
            part1_runs += 1  # Increment the counter
           
        elif count < 0.68:
            count+=0.05
            time.sleep(0.64)
       
       
        # Yield the chunk to the client
        yield chunk


It's unclear. Edit the question for correctness of English. Also post a [mre] and debugging details.

@relent95 the answer was really easy, we where using time.sleep instead of system.system()

If you don't want to edit the question, why not delete it? This question in its current state is not useful to others.
